# The POST request I have is always undefined, and can't read my JSON object

Tags: node.js, fs, fetch-api, body-parser

So I am building some Blog software with FS and Express, with BodyParser. Anyhow, when I send a POST request (using the Fetch API)

When I enter the correct password (as an .env variable in config.js file) it says that it's incorrect, and the guess was undefined. I've tried quite a lot, but nothing works. (My undo() function removes symbols and returns the output.)

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ strict:false }));
app.post("/newpost", (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.password == config.PASSWORD) {
    fs.writeFile("/blog/" + undo(req.body.name) + ".md", req.body.context, (err) => {
      console.log("Probably made file. Error: " + err);
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Someone tried guessing and making a blog on your Blog. Stay safe. Their guess was " + req.body.password + ".");
  }
});
```

And here is the function for adding a new blog:

```js
var xv=prompt("Enter the password.");
var ob = {password: xv, name: document.getElementById("title").innerText, context: document.getElementById("context").innerHTML};
fetch("/newpost",{method:"POST", body:JSON.stringify(ob)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are converting to string,  here-

```
var xv=prompt("Enter the password.");
var ob = {password: xv, name: document.getElementById("title").innerText, context: document.getElementById("context").innerHTML};
fetch("/newpost",{method:"POST", body:JSON.stringify(ob)});
```

You need to convert back to object here

````
app.use(bodyParser.json({ strict:false }));
app.post("/newpost", (req, res) => {
  req.body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  if (req.body.password == config.PASSWORD) {
    fs.writeFile("/blog/" + undo(req.body.name) + ".md", req.body.context, (err) => {
      console.log("Probably made file. Error: " + err);
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Someone tried guessing and making a blog on your Blog. Stay safe. Their guess was " + req.body.password + ".");
  }
});```
````